# Is it possible to set the active range with Apache POI XSSF?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am using Apache POI XSSF to read and write Excel Sheets.

I know that I can set the active cell on a worksheet by using `Sheet.setActiveCell(CellAddress address)`.

However, I'd like to  set it to a Range containing more than one cell on the sheet, as illustrated by the picture below:

[image: Range selected in Excel Sheet]

When I save a sheet with multiple cells selected using Excel those are selected upon opening the saved file. 
Is there a way to do this with POI XSSF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following line to achieve a ranke as active cell in excel:

```
    sheet.setActiveCell("A1:B2");
```

Hope it helps.

As from 3.16 onwards the setActiveCell(String) method is deprecated and you do not want to use a deprecated method I would suggest to create your own CellAddress:

```
public class CellRangeAddress extends CellAddress {

    private CellAddress start;
    private CellAddress end;

    public CellRangeAddress(final CellAddress start, final CellAddress end) {
        super(start);
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }


    @Override
    public String formatAsString() {
        if (end != null) {
            return start.formatAsString() + ":" + end.formatAsString();
        }
        return super.formatAsString();
    }
}
```

and use ist like:

```
sheet.setActiveCell(new CellRangeAddress(new CellAddress("A1"), new CellAddress("B2")));
```

Not the cleanest and best way, but works without warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works. However, this method seems to be deprecated, but I cannot find an adequate replacement. 
For instance, this does not work, since setActiveCell only accepts CellAddress as input:

`CellRangeAddress adr = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B2");
        wb.getSheetAt(wb.getActiveSheetIndex()).setActiveCell(adr);`

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: I am using 3.16, which seems to be the most recent one.

Comment: I edited my answer, still not the best solution, but one option

Comment: Thank you very much, that'll do fine. It is a little unfortunate that this functionality was deprecated in an update without any replacement, I think.

Comment: Why are you using such a complicated way to build the `CellRangeAddress`? Why not just do [`CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B2")](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Because in 3.16 `CellRangeAddress.valueOf()` is giving you a `CellRangeAddress` but in 3.16 `Sheet.setActiveCell` does not accept it. Only `String` which is deprecated or `CellAddress`.