# Apache Poi setActiveCell() for multiple cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to use the method `sheet.setActiveCell(CellAddress addr)` to set a range of multiple cells active at the same time. I've tryed with multiple versions of Apache poi-ooxml library and now i'm using 3.16 which also supports the method `sheet.setActiveCell(String addr)`(I know 3.16 is old but the issue stays the same also with the latest version).

Following the suggestions on this question: [Is it possible to set the active range with Apache POI XSSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541809/is-it-possible-to-set-the-active-range-with-apache-poi-xssf)
I've managed to get it to work, both with the custom CellAddress and the String in the format "A1:B5".

The problem is that every time I try to open an xlsx in which a range of cells has been set to active using apache poi, I get an error message from Excel saying that the file is damaged and need to be recovered. If I do, the recovery completes correctly, but this error is annoying since I have to open a great number of these files each day.

Is there a way to avoid this error from excel (maybe modifying the creation of the xlsx or changing some setting in Excel)?

Comment: Only one cell can be the active cell. Do you mean set multiple selected cells?

Comment: Yes, my goal was to pre-select a group of cells, to find them already selected when opening the xlsx file. I thought that, to achieve this I would have to set them as active, but if there is a way to just select them, I'm ok with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one cell can be the active cell. And `Sheet.setActiveCell` only sets that one active cell. So `sheet.setActiveCell("A1:B5")` will work if `setActiveCell(String addr)` is available but it leads to a corrupted sheet. That's why it was removed.

Multiple cells can be selected. But there are no methods to set the selected cells in `apache poi`'s high level classes. So the underlying low level classes needs to be used. Doing this one needs differentiate between `XSSF` and `HSSF` because different low level classes needs to be used.

Following complete example sets active cell to `B2`. This also sets sheet view having selection and active cell to that one given cell `B2`. Then it uses low level methods of `XSSF` and `HSSF` to set the selection to `B2:E5`.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

class CreateExcelSelectMultipleCells {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {
  //try (Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row;
   Cell cell;
     
   for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue("R" + (r+1) + "C" + (c+1));
    }
   }

   // set active cell; this also sets sheet view having selection and active cell to one given cell
   sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress("B2"));
   // set selected cells 
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet) sheet;
    xssfSheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews().getSheetViewArray(0).getSelectionArray(0).setSqref(
     java.util.Arrays.asList("B2:E5"));
   } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
    HSSFSheet hssfSheet = (HSSFSheet) sheet; 
    org.apache.poi.hssf.record.SelectionRecord selectionRecord = hssfSheet.getSheet().getSelection();
    java.lang.reflect.Field field_6_refs = org.apache.poi.hssf.record.SelectionRecord.class.getDeclaredField("field_6_refs");
    field_6_refs.setAccessible(true);
    field_6_refs.set(
     selectionRecord, 
     new org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress8Bit[] { new org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress8Bit(1,4,1,4) }
    );
   }
   
   workbook.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution solved the problem perfectly!